# UpdateQuery doesn't execute. How to fix this code?

Tags: java, database, xampp, swingx

I want to get the date in **DATE** column and want to compare with the **current date**. if the date is `less` than **current date** then I want to **SET** the value of **PERMISSION** column `allow`. But my Query doesn't execute.

Which I have tried is given in my below code.

```java
Date date1 = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
//current date
Date date = new Date();
date1 = date;
CurrentDate.setText(date1.toString());
String UpdateQuery = null;
String Allow = "allow";
UpdateQuery = "UPDATE company SET permission = '"+Allow+"' WHERE date < ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);                 
SimpleDateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String addDate = CurrentDate.getText();
pst.setString(2, addDate);
pst.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Updated");
```

> I want to get a value of `permission table` to SET to "allow" when the update query is executing;

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: JAVA version:  1.8.0_111

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't update"? do you get an actual error, or does the value in your db just not update?

Comment: can you provide log/error which you are facing?

Comment: Stultuske..... Bro... I didn't get any error. I mean the Update query doesn't execute.

Comment: iamrajshah  Bro..... I haven't get any error..... supporse my code is 
                   ' System.out.println("one");     //line 1
                    pst.executeUpdate();                         //line 2
                    System.out.println("Updated");         //line 3'
                    after run the program I have got line 1 in output.. but havent get line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pst.setString(2, addDate);`

I think this should be changed to:

`pst.setString(1, addDate);`

because you only have one parameter in your prepared statement.

Also, when comparing dates, you need to enclose them in single quotes, so changing your **UpdateQuery** string to
`"UPDATE company SET permission = '"+Allow+"' WHERE date < '?' ";`

is also a necessary step.

Comment: I changed it to 1... but didn't get any changes to result.

Comment: Try changing **UpdateQuery** to `"UPDATE company SET permission = '"+Allow+"' WHERE date < '?' ";`  Databases generally need the date to be in single quotes, or else it will be evaluated as a math expression, i.e. 2000-05-20 without single quotes is just 1975.

Comment: Then it could be some other database connectivity issue, are other queries from your app executed correctly?

Comment: Bro... I just find out and fixed this issue....  yes bro.... My date format in java program was incompatible with xampp date format